# How to show $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}} = \frac{2\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}}{5}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, rationalising-denominator

Show that:
$$ \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt2+\sqrt3}=\dfrac{2\sqrt2-\sqrt3}{5}$$

So I multiplied everything by $\sqrt3$

Then I got 
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}+3}$$
Then multiply it by $\sqrt2$ to obtain

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}}{2 \cdot 3+3}$$
Which is $$\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}}{9}$$ which isn't equal to $$\frac{2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{5}$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hi @JohnFire, use [help] for correct formatting.

Comment: In your first step when you multiply by $\sqrt{3}$ on the bottom, you need to multiply both terms, not just the $\sqrt{3}$ term.

Comment: You also made the same type of mistake that Sean English pointed out when you multiplied by $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: For $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ with b,d non-zero, we have it being equivalent to $ad=bc$, visually the product of 'diagonal'(a,d) and 'anti-diagonal'(c,b) elements. And here you can use this with $(x+y)(x-y)=x^2-y^2$.

Comment: By the distributive property $\sqrt{3}(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) = 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}=\dots$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As one of the comments stated, your first error lies in the first step where you multiply "everything" by $\sqrt{3}$. While you claim to do this, you did not multiply *both* terms in the denominator by $\sqrt{3}$. This was an error that let you to an incorrect expression.

That having been said, your approach is not correct. To show this equality, you have to simplify the expression on the left hand side. In this case, because you have radical expressions in the denominator, that means multiplying the top and bottom by the "right value" which will eliminate the radicals. In the case of a single term in the denominator like $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, you would simply multiply the top and bottom by $\sqrt{2}$ which would yield $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

The case you have, however, contains a binomial in the denominator (meaning two terms). In this case, you should multiply by the conjugate of the denominator. So for your example, the conjugate of $2\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ would be $2\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}$. Doing so yields the following:
\begin{align}
   \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}} \cdot \frac{2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}} &= \frac{2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{(2\sqrt{2})^2 - (\sqrt{3})^2} \\
&= \frac{2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{8 - 3} \\
&= \frac{2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{5}
\end{align}
Thus we've shown that $$ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}} = \frac{2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{5}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tho my book only mentioned the $$1/sqrt x = sqrt x/x$$ rule, and then the exercises are way harder then that.

Comment: Nice first answer Gustavo!

Comment: Haha thanks Winther :)

Comment: May I just ask why is that we multiply by the conjugate? Or can I find the deduction of this process somewhere? @GustavoPoscidonio

Answer (score 5):

$$(2\sqrt2-\sqrt3)(2\sqrt2+\sqrt3)=(2\sqrt2)^2-(\sqrt3)^2=?$$

Answer (score 4):

The *conjugate* of $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$ is $\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}$.  To rationalize an expression of the form $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}}$$ we multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}$.  Since the conjugate of $2\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ is $2\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}} & = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}} \cdot \frac{2\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}} && \text{multiply by the conjugate}\\
                               & = \frac{2\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}}{(2\sqrt{2})^2 - (\sqrt{3})^2} && \text{since $(a + b)(a - b) = a^2 - b^2$}\\
                               & = \frac{2\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}}{8 - 3}\\
                               & = \frac{2\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}}{5}
\end{align*}

As for your mistakes, you did not apply the distributive law when you multiplied the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{3}$.  You should have obtained 
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{6} + 3}$$
You also failed to distribute the factor of $\sqrt{2}$ in the denominator in the next step.  Once you obtained $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{6} + 3}$$ you could have multiplied the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator, which is $-2\sqrt{6} + 3$, then simplified.

Comment: Very good. Glad to see a nice, detailed and pedagogical answer pitched at OPs level apposed to lazy one liner.

Comment: Thank you very much, really clear answer. May I just ask why do we multiple both the numerator and the denominator by the conjugate of the denominator?  When there is only one square root in the denominator, we can easily simplify, using the $$x/\sqrt\x =\sqrt\x/x$$ -multiplying by the denominator. Why doesn't that work in these cases?

Comment: If we have something like $$\frac{12}{\sqrt{6}}$$ we rationalize the denominator by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{6}$ to obtain $$\frac{12}{\sqrt{6}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{6}} = \frac{12\sqrt{6}}{6} = 2\sqrt{6}$$  However, if we have a sum (or difference) in the denominator, just multiplying by the term inside the radical will not rationalize the denominator.  For instance, $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3 + 2\sqrt{6}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{6}} = \frac{\sqrt{18}}{3\sqrt{6} + 2 \cdot 6} = \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{6} + 12} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4 + \sqrt{6}}$$

Comment: To add to my previous comment, in order to rationalize a term of the form $a + \sqrt{b}$ or $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$, we must multiply by its conjugate in order to rationalize the denominator.  The conjugate of $a + \sqrt{b}$ is $a - \sqrt{b}$.  When we multiply the conjugates, we obtain $$(a + \sqrt{b})(a - \sqrt{b}) = a^2 - (\sqrt{b})^2 = a^2 - b$$ which is rational if $a$ and $b$ are.  The conjugate of $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$ is $\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}$.  The product of the conjugates $(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}) = \sqrt{a})^2 - \sqrt{b}^2 = a^2 - b^2$ is rational if $a$ and $b$ are.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\frac {1}{2\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3}= \frac {2\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3}{5}&\iff \\\frac {1}{2\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3}\cdot  {2\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3} = \frac {2\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3}{5}\cdot  {(2\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)} &\iff\\
1=\frac {(2\sqrt2)^2-(\sqrt 3)^2}{5}&\iff\\
1=\frac {4\cdot 2-3}{5}&\iff 1=\frac 5 5.
\end{align}